# Solving 4T(n/5) + log5(n * sqrt(n)) with the master theorem

Tags: algorithm, math, recurrence, master-theorem

I'm trying to solve the recursion 4T(n/5) + log5(n * sqrt(n)) with the master theorem but I've run into some difficulties.

I understand using the form T(n) = a T(n/b) + theta(n^k log^p n) would yield:

```
a = 4
b = 5
k = 0
```

but how would I deal with the n * sqrt n within the log? I cannot understand how to proceed. Thanks

Comment: Think through log identities. There’s a way to transform it into the form you showed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you should ask it on math.stackexchange.com, rather than here.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I'll attempt that, thank you!

Comment: @PeterO. It's in reference to O notation of software algorithms, but I do see your perspective, I would say it doesn't hurt.

Comment: Algorithm analysis is very much on topic here. If there _were_ a second site it should be on, cs.se would likely be more appropriate than math.se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`log(n * sqrt(n)) = log(n^{1.5}) = 1.5* log(n)`

thus your formula becomes
`T(n) = 4T(n/5) + 1.5 * log5(n)`

Comment: Ah I didn't catch that log identity with the power of n. Thank you very much for your help!